# Don't understand why my program is running the way that it is

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to create a Java program that uses numerical values of characters (A=1, B=2, C=3...) The program will give the user a word (ie "BABY", "CHILD"...) and the user can add subtract, multiply, and divide the letters to get new letters (A+A=B).

```
package QUASSINOBALLY;
import java.util.*;
import stdlib.*;

public class YeahBitch {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Dictionary<String,Integer> d = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("baby");
        list.add("child");
        list.add("hog");
        Random rand = new Random();
        String question = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
        question = question.toUpperCase();
        System.out.print(question+"\n");
        d.put("A",1);
        d.put("B",2);
        d.put("C",3);
        d.put("D",4);
        d.put("E",5);
        d.put("F",6);
        d.put("G",7);
        d.put("H",8);
        d.put("I",9);
        d.put("J",10);
        d.put("K",11);
        d.put("L",12);
        d.put("M",13);
        d.put("N",14);
        d.put("O",15);
        d.put("P",16);
        d.put("Q",17);
        d.put("R",18);
        d.put("S",19);
        d.put("T",20);
        d.put("U",21);
        d.put("V",22);
        d.put("W",23);
        d.put("X",24);
        d.put("Y",25);
        d.put("Z",26);
        System.out.println("Enter your answer here.");
        String answer = StdIn.readString();
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        List<String> operators = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-","*","/"));
        for(int i =0;i<answer.length();i++){
            if (!operators.contains(Character.toString(answer.charAt(i)))){
                System.out.println("character number:"+i);
                System.out.println("character it is now:"+Character.toString(answer.charAt(i)));
                System.out.println("character it is going to be:"+d.get(Character.toString(answer.charAt(i))));
                answer = answer.replaceFirst(Character.toString(answer.charAt(i)),(d.get(Character.toString(answer.charAt(i))).toString()));
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Finished!");



        }
}
```

The print statements were used in an attempt to help debug, and may help you debug.

The program works runs but other times it doesn't.

Examples of times when it runs: "a+b+c+d","d+c+b+a","d+c+b+d"...'

Examples of times when it doesn't run: "b+a+b+y","c+h+i+l+d"...

It seems that there are various times when the program breaks, in the example of "b+a+b+y" which has character values 0-6, the program inspects element 7 and gets a value of "5". I have been trying to debug this for a while and haven't made much progress. Is there a specific area of the code that is too messy to work? I would prefer tips rather than someone telling me an explicit answer.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: share the output you get. why is it wrong?

Comment: I don't see any `%` in there. When you add baby (2 + 1 + 2 + 25) you get 30. Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do here(quite possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with the positions in the string when reading and writing. In "CHILD" it goes well up until L, since L = 12 it is written at two positions. Then instead of reading "D" it read the next char "2" and since "2" is not defined it gives a null pointer.

This is what I get on my console running the code:

```
character number:3
character it is now:L
character it is going to be:12
38912D
character number:4
character it is now:2
character it is going to be:null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You must jump over the two-digit number to read the next letter. That`s why for inputs like "a+b+c+d","d+c+b+a","d+c+b+d" runs correctly, since their numerical value is less than 10.

Comment: Thanks so much! Did some adjustments based on this comment and the program runs in every case now.